# Connecting to ec2 instance after creating a Load balancer

Tags: putty, amazon-ec2, load-balancer, aws-cloud9, aws-ses

How do I connect to an ec2 instance after creating a load balancer ? I have the below configuration set up:

1. Two RHEL 8 ec2 instances
2. Both the instances are inside a VPC but in two availability zones.
3. Both the instances are associated with separate public subnets and IGW is set up properly.
4. Both the instances have private + Elastic IPs
5. The load balancer is ELB

I am using PuTTy to connect to the instances and can access two instances separately using their elastic IPs. But How do I connect to the load balancer so that it connects me to any of the two instances ?

PS: I am a beginner in aws so if my question is somewhere confusing/unclear, please let me know. Many thanks.

Comment: what type of load balancer is it? AWS has several to choose from: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/load-balancer-types.html

Comment: It’s Elastic load balancer

Comment: It’s internet facing, network type load ELB. Listener is active on TCP port 22 and 80

Comment: Have you checked the ELB security group ? Is it the same as your ec2 instance ?